# String index out of range error in Java (String index out of bounds exception )

Tags: java, recursion

everyone so I'm writing a code that should take "aabbcc" and output "abc" so deleting the repeated characters using recursion. Hope you could help me out.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringReverser
{
public static String getReverser(String i)
{
  if (i==(" "))
        return "";
    if (i.charAt(0)==i.charAt(1))
        return i.substring(1) + getReverser(i.substring(2));
    else
    return getReverser(i.substring(1));
 }

 public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a String");
  String in = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println(getReverser(in));
 }
}
```

And when I run my code i get this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
     String index out of range: 1
     at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
     at StringReverser.getReverser(StringReverser.java:9)
     at StringReverser.getReverser(StringReverser.java:12)
     at StringReverser.getReverser(StringReverser.java:10)
    at StringReverser.main(StringReverser.java:20)`

Comment: Well, what if you hit `if (i.charAt(0)==i.charAt(1))` and the string is only one character long?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Still the same error

Comment: @MaxZoom so what does that mean exactly ?

Comment: If  you want to compare two characters in string, then there has to be a check if string contains two characters. Otherwise there is nothing to compare to and you access memory outside the String space (StringIndexOutOfBounds).

Comment: Use .equals() when comparing strings. Also check for empty string/single character instead of space. Still this algorithm wont work, but you wont get the error.

Comment: When your string is down to one character, you cannot go any further.  You need a base case for when `i.length() <= 1`.

Comment: @NickClark2016 and what should be its return value, i only ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use split? This is easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution. You were close!

You want to keep returning the word if it's only one character (otherwise you'll get an out of bounds exception).

If the characters next to one another are the same, then return a new word that only keeps the rightmost character (skipping a duplicate).

```
public static String getReverser(String word) {
    System.out.println(word);
    if (word.length() == 1) {
        return word;
    }
    if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(1)) {
        return getReverser(word.substring(1));
    } else {
        return word.substring(0, 1) + getReverser(word.substring(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a String: 
aabbccccaa
aabbccccaa
abbccccaa
bbccccaa
bccccaa
ccccaa
cccaa
ccaa
caa
aa
a
abca
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate !!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a String");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    char[] charArray = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
    for(char chr : charArray){
        if(builder.indexOf(String.valueOf(chr))==-1){
            builder.append(chr);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(builder);
}
```